# "IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 0" in PyTorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, anaconda3

Coding environment:

- anaconda
- conda: v.4.10.3
- jupyter

Package dependencies:

- Python: v.3.7.11
- PyTorch: v.1.10.0, py3.7_cpu_0, pytorch

I'm a beginner in PyTorch.

I have bellow codes and I didn't use transforms in it:

Generally this code wants to show the differences between a Deep Neural Network Model with and without using dropout.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

import numpy as np

# ------------------------- Model classe
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_size, n_hidden, out_size, p=0):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.drop = nn.Dropout(p = p)
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(in_size, n_hidden)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_hidden)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(n_hidden, out_size)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.linear1(x))
        x = self.drop(x)
        
        x = torch.relu(self.linear2(x))
        x = self.drop(x)
        
        x = self.linear3(x)
        
        return x

# ------------------------- Data set class
class Data(Dataset):
    
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, N_SAMPLES=1000, noise_std=0.15, train=True):
        a = np.matrix([-1, 1, 2, 1, 1, -3, 1]).T
        self.a = a
        self.x = np.matrix(np.random.rand(N_SAMPLES, 2))
        self.f = np.array(a[0] + 
                          (self.x) * a[1: 3] + 
                          np.multiply(self.x[:, 0], self.x[:, 1]) * a[4] + 
                          np.multiply(self.x, self.x) * a[5: 7]).flatten()
        
        
        self.y = np.zeros(N_SAMPLES)
        self.y[self.f > 0] = 1
        self.y = torch.from_numpy(self.y).type(torch.LongTensor)
        
        self.x = torch.from_numpy(self.x).type(torch.FloatTensor)
        self.x = self.x + noise_std * torch.randn(self.x.size())
        
        self.f = torch.from_numpy(self.f)
        
        if train == True:
            torch.manual_seed(1)
            self.x = self.x + noise_std * torch.randn(self.x.size())
            torch.manual_seed(0)
            
    # Getter
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.x[index], self.y[index]
    
    # Get Length
    def __len__(self):
        return self.len

model = Net(2, 300, 2, p=0)

model_drop = Net(2, 300, 2, p=0.5)
model_drop.train()

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model_drop.parameters(), lr=0.01)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

data_set = Data()
validation_set = Data(train=False)

loss = {}
loss["training_data_no_dropout"] = []
loss["validation_data_no_dropout"] = []
loss["training_data_dropout"] = []
loss["validation_data_dropout"] = []

# ------------------------- training
for epoch in range(500):
    # all the samples are used for training
    yhat = model(data_set.x)
    yhat_drop = model_drop(data_set.x)
    loss = criterion(yhat, data_set.y)
    loss_drop = criterion(yhat_drop, data_set.y)
    
    # store the loss for both the training and validation data for both models
    loss["training_data_no_dropout"].append(loss.item())
    loss["validation_data_no_dropout"].append(criterion(model(validation_set.x), validation_set.y).item())
    loss["training_data_dropout"].append(loss_drop.item)
    model_drop.eval()
    loss["validation_data_dropout"].appent(criterion(model_drop(validation_set.x), validation_set.y).item())
    model_drop.train()
    
    optimizer_ofit.zero_grad()
    optimizer_drop.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    loss_drop.backward()
    optimizer_ofit.step()
    optimizer_drop.step()
```

but I got this error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4212/2392693530.py in <module>
      7 
      8     # store the loss for both the training and validation data for both models
----> 9     loss["training_data_no_dropout"].append(loss.item())
     10     loss["validation_data_no_dropout"].append(criterion(model(validation_set.x), validation_set.y).item())
     11     loss["training_data_dropout"].append(loss_drop.item)

IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 0
```

Questions:

- why I got this error?
- How can I fix it?

I will be appreciate for any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that the entire error, or you truncated it ? Also, can you show me the content of the `loss` variable ?

Comment: furst use `print()`, to see what you have in variables (values, types, sizes/shapes, etc.) - it is called `"print debuging"`